# On-Refresh routing issue with Angular 4 and Laravel 5.4

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing, angular4-router

I have created a simple application with Angular 4 and Laravel 5.4 for doing CRUD operation.

So, basically I have an angular app running on localhost:4200 and Laravel app (for api's ony) running on localhost:8000

Now I have integrated angular 4 into Laravel using

```
 ng build
```

Now my application is completely running on localhost:8000 Perfect!

Now the issue scene!

[image: Angular app working fine with laravel][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4H8B.png)
[image: It's taking angular route properly][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Edl.png)
[image: When I refresh the page, it is looking for laravel route and this is what happenng.][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAnej.png)

So, as you can see, it is taking angular routes but when I refresh the same page it is looking for laravel route. How to resolve this issue?

> Laravel routes are only using as the api for angular for data transfer in 
>   json.

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this has been addressed in the `Deployment` section of the official Angular docs. Problem is, an Angular app is a single page application, which means it only has an `index.html` file, and all other routes are managed by the angular browser **client side**. 
If you come from page A to page B, you already have an Angular app which handles the redirect. If you refresh though, the browser will address the API, which does not contain your page requested.

It means you need to configure your server. If you are deploying live, use this .htaccess configuration for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

It will just return the `index.html` file of your Angular app to be rendered. otherwise configure your Laravel routing to do the same thing.

Rad more on the issue here: [Angular Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is an angular app which is integrated with laravel and it is running in laravel server.

Comment: As I have mentioned, just configure your routing to return `index.html` of your Angular app if route not found. This will solve the issue. You do not need to keep track of **every** Angular route, just if 404, then maybe it is an Angular route and better to return `index.html`

Comment: It may also be nice to have an Anguar 404 page, just use `'**'` as a route

Comment: So do I need to change laravel htaccess ?

Comment: I am no specialist in Laravel, but if you have a .htaccess file, then just copy paste the exempt from my answer - should do the job

Comment: Yeah I have tried with your htaccess, but its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel 7 and Angular 9.

This Answer is without using the `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})`

Steps:

1) Build your app using, ng build, the default `<base href="/">`.

2) Copy all your files from dist/`<project name>` to Laravel folder, public.

3) From Laravel public folder, move/cut `index.html` file only, to Laravel resources/views

4) Rename `index.html` to `index.blade.php`

5) On Laravel routes folder, open `web.php`, remove and replace.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Replace with:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

So that all links that are not found 404 error will be redirect to index.blade.php
Thats all!

[Laravel public folder structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3vds.png)

Comment: Or if you are lazy, after moving public/index.html to resources/views/welcome.blade.php, just add to web.php:

Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Answer (score 0):

For all routes in angular you need to route to index action in Laravel.

**Try:**

```
foreach(['/', '/about', '/another_route'] as $route){
    Route::get($route,[
        'uses'=>'siteController@index',
        'as'=>'index'
     ]);
}
```

All these URLs will be redirected to the same entry point, view (usually home page) rendered by action `siteController@index` and then the angular router will handle routing to the right location.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please tell me what should be inside index function ?

Comment: Home page is loading from angular route. So if am in register page (localhost:8000/register) and refresh, i should get that same register page. not the home page.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I have solved the issue. Thanks for all comments and reply's to my question.
If someone is going through same issue, then implement :

> hashlocationstrategy in angular 4

I have just added one parameter in routes module of angular and it worked fine.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true}),
```

[For more details, check here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/)